# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: You provided using Observable.from()

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a function below which returns the result as a promise and want to convert it to observable to process it further.

```
isAuthenticated(): () => Promise<boolean> {
  return async () => {
    const payload: any = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
    const isExpired = payload?.token ? this.helper.isTokenExpired(payload.token) : true;
    const isAuthenticated = await this.nbAuthService.isAuthenticated().toPromise();
    return !isExpired && isAuthenticated;
  };
}
```

And the Observable function:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  const observable = from(this.authService.isAuthenticated());
  return observable.pipe(
    tap(authenticated => {
      if (!authenticated) {
        this.router.navigate(['/auth/sign-in']);
      }
    }),
  );
}
```

It throws an error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: You provided '() =>
> Object(tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["__awaiter"])(this, void 0,
> void 0, function* () {
> const payload = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
> const isExpired = (payload === null || payload === void 0 ? void 0 : payload.token) ? this.helper.isTokenExpired(payload.token)
> : true;
> const isAuthenticated = yield this.nbAuthService.isAuthenticated().toPromise();
> return !isExpired && isAuthenticated;

Answer (score 0):

Blockquote

ok how about you change your isAuthenticated function to return an observable like below

```
isAuthenticated():Observable<boolean> {


return  from(this.nbAuthService.isAuthenticated().toPromise())
.pipe(
    map(isAuthenticated=>{ 
    const payload: any = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
    const isExpired = payload?.token ? this.helper.isTokenExpired(payload.token) : true;
    return !isExpired && isAuthenticated); })
    
    };
 }
```

Comment: The return is Promise not Observable. `Promise<boolean>`

Comment: in your original code you had this.nbAuthService.isAuthenticated().toPromise();.. is nbAuthService a different service ??

Comment: my bad .. in that case you can simply get your isAuthenticated function to return observable .. see the above